# java RMI is giving java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Tags: java, rmi

I am trying to create an simple rmi chat but I coldnt get through this exception.i think I have done it right but I must be missing something
this is where the exception occurs

```
  HelloClient(String name,HelloInterface hello) throws RemoteException{

     this.name=name;
     this.hello=hello;
     try{hello.register(this);}///this is the line generating my exception
     catch(Exception es){System.out.println(es);}}
```

I have the register() method in my server interface and I have also implemented it

```
public synchronized void register(HelloClient h) throws RemoteException {
   //code of my implementation which is not neccerary
                  }//on my server side passing it the client object
```

and this is the exception I am getting
       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

I have tried to make myclient class implement serizable but it didn't work.
so ca anyone please give me a hand

Comment: How is the code throwing the exception not relevant? Read the stack trace and the code it points to.

Comment: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@178655

Comment: even if I take out all the code from my register method and make it empty,the exception is still there

Comment: the rmi chat is not specific first is it about a peer2peer RMI or Server Client Rmi i can help you if you specify more your need

Comment: are you trying a callback here ...

Comment: I am trying server client rmi.here is what I want,when the client runs the program, object of hello client needs to be sent to the servers class. Just assume i have class server, client and serverint as an interface. I state my register() method in my interface and implement it in the server class and it takes client object as argument.so ho can I call register() in the client class constructor passing it client.this object.

Comment: and I just tried to change my register() method argument to string register(string x) and I got this exception  [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@43da1b
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
 java.rmi.UnmarshalException: unrecognized method hash: method not supported by remote object

Answer (score 0):

You've changed your remote interface after deployment. Clean, recompile, and redeploy.